# Sigmoid Curve function calculation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponentiation

So I am learning about Sigmoid Curves and in this article it says the formula is:
$$\tag{1}
    \frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta_0-\beta_1x}}
$$
Then it gives an example problem: Let’s say you take $ \beta_0 = -15$ and $\beta_1 = 0.065$. Now, what will be the probability of diabetes for a patient with sugar level $220$?

---

And the answer is given as follows:

The probability of diabetes for a person with sugar level $x$ is given by $\mathrm{P}(\mathrm{Diabetes})=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta_0-\beta_1x}}$. Now, taking $\beta_0=−15$ and $\beta_1=0.065$, the probability of diabetes for a person with sugar level $220$ will be given by

$$\mathrm{P(Diabetes)}= \frac{1}{1+e^{15-0.065\cdot 220}}\approx 0.33$$

So the answer is $0.33$. But I am not sure how they reached this result. I know that $-15+ 0.065\cdot 220 = -0.7$, but I dont know how the whole equation computes to $0.33$

Can anyone help in understanding? My math knowledge is very poor so I appreciate any help!

Comment: There are some typos/mistakes in your equations. Please verify that the corrections that I made to the first expression are correct. That is, that the signs of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ in expression (1). When I make the calculations myself, it seems like their signs should be negative.

Comment: Next point: The last result that you wrote says $-15+0.065 \cdot 220 = 0.6$, this is incorrect. Please re-calculate that.

Comment: So anyway, the final calculation looks like this:
$$
\frac{1}{1+e^{-(-15+0.065\cdot 220)}} \approx 0.33
$$
which looks to be correct. If you have problems evaluating this, perhaps the problem arises at taking the exponent function $e^{\text{something}}$, right? What kind of calculator are you using?

Comment: @MattiP. Please ignore my UTTER ignorance in this matter! I am not using any calculator. I am trying to do this in excel and I have no idea how to :( Can you show me how to calculate this in excel or some online calculating site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just go ahead and post this as an answer. In Excel, you can write:

```
=1/(1+EXP(-(-15+0.065*220)))
```

which returns $\approx 0.3318$. Another way to evaluate the expression, in Wolfram Alpha, is here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281%2Be%5E%28-%28-15%2B0.065*220%29%29%29

So the lesson to take home from this, is that in Excel you just need to use the EXP function to calculate the exponentiation. And remember to use proper parentheses.

Comment: Thank you! I am unable to upvote your answer, but I will as soon as I have enough reputation!

Answer (score 0):

The value of exponent e is 2.7182818.
So, −(-15+0.065⋅220)= 15 - 14.3 = 0.7

then 1/1+0.7 i.e. 1/1+e power to 0.7 is 1/1+(2.7182818) power to 7
= 1/1+2.01375 = 1/3.01375 = 0.33181252592 Ans

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1997182)